# Throwing exception after finishing for loop with custom message

Tags: java, error-handling

How would I go about passing variables of a failed method using Exceptions? I have a for loop where every time an iteration of the loop fails, it adds the variable to a list of failed items which will then get passed to an exception and printed using getMessage().

```
public class SendMail {
    public void send(List<String> inputlist) throws MessagingException {
            List<String> failedItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String item : inputlist) {
                try {
                    // Do something
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    failedRecipients.add(item);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // Custom exception with string of failed items.
            if (!failedItems.isEmpty()) {
                throw new MessagingException(String.join(",", failedItems));
            }
        }
}
```

```
public class ProcessStep {
public void execute(List<String> inputlist) throws XferException {
            try {
                sendmail.send(inputlist); //String list gets passed here.
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                log.logger("Failed for items: " + e.getMessage()) //Print string of failed items here
            }
            throw new MalwareException;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom exception with a constructor that takes any number of parameters.